# Changing colour of annotation pin with Apple's new annotation pin logo

Tags: swift, annotations, uicolor, mkannotation

I'm trying to change the colour of my annotation pins. However, I am wanting it to change the colour of the new Apple annotation logo. Instead, when the colours change, the new logo (as shown below) converts to the old logo (as shown below).

Is there anyway to change the colour as well as keep the new annotation pin?

Here's my code:

```
class MyPointAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation {
    var pinTintColor: UIColor?
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "myAnnotation") as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myAnnotation")
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
       } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    if let annotation = annotation as? MyPointAnnotation {
        annotationView?.pinTintColor = annotation.pinTintColor
    }
            return annotationView
}

self.map.delegate = self
/// in view did load
```

Old pin:

[image: Old pin]

New pin:

[image: new pin]

any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use [MKMarkerAnnotationView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmarkerannotationview) instead of MKPinAnnotationView.

```
if annotationView == nil {
    annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myAnnotation")
    annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
   } else {
    annotationView?.annotation = annotation
}
```

MKMarkerAnnotationView uses [markerTintColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmarkerannotationview/2873822-markertintcolor) rather than pinTintColor.
However, this only works on iOS 11.
The new icon is only present in iOS 11.